# Back button functionality c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently I'm in say Page A. The URL is http://localhost:22507/PageA.aspx. From there select a dropdown value. Now the same page shows some extra data and an edit button along with the dropdown. Page URL is still http://localhost:22507/PageA.aspx. When I click the Edit button its redirected to another page Page B. And the present URL is http://localhost:22507/PageB.aspx?qstr=6EysKHDt1+a/m8SQcruQOCVgWF+9+PCfmydyeX5wbKU=

While clicking the Back button in the Page B, it directly goes to the first state. ie, I've to again select the drop down, click edit etc.

How can I go back to the just previous state(Page A with data and Edit button) after clicking Back button?

Now I use `Response.Redirect("PageA.aspx", false);` for redirecting

Comment: You can use `OnClientClick="JavaScript: window.history.back(1); return false;"`

Comment: Look at pushState at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API.  This creates a new history record which you can use the back button to navigate to.  Use javacsript to check the query string and display the appropriate state.  Alternatively you could use cookies to store the user history and "remember" what they were looking at last.

Answer (score 0):

When changing the selected list item, use pushState to update the browser address bar and history to record the change of state.  E.g instead of the address bar still displaying /PageA.aspx, it could instead show /PageA.aspx?selected=1.

If you then use the back button from PageB.aspx?qstr=6EysKHDt1+a/m8SQcruQOCVgWF+9+PCfmydyeX5wbKU=, pressing back will return you to PageA.aspx?selected=1.  You can then parse the query string to determine the correct state to display.

Mozilla provides documentation on pushState here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API.

Note that for older browsers there are some compatibility issues.  A clunky old method that would work would be to reload the page with a query string when the dropdown is changed, allowing the back button to work in much the same way.  An alternative that avoids reloading the page may be to update a cookie with a flag indicating the state.  On loading the page, check for the cookie and flag.  However, then you would need to consider expiry of the cookie (ie what if they didn't press back but instead navigated to pageA again through some other means, would loading the saved state still be acceptable?).